# What is the equivalent of a single threaded ExecutorService in RxJava?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, rx-java2

I wish to use RxJava in place of my single threaded `ExecutorService`:

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(/* ... */);
```

I was wondering what is the equivalent setup using RxJava?
What I have tried so far:

```
private Subject<MyClass> subject = PublishSubject.create()
subject.toFlowable(MISSING)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .subscribe(obj -> {
            // handle on next
        });
```

Is this equivalent to the `ExecutorService` setup I have above or different? Do I get a new single threaded executor with `Schedulers.single()`?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the lifecycle of your `ExecutorService`. If it is an application-wide and is tied to its entire lifecycle, then `Schedulers.single()` is equivalent to it.

If you have several, single threaded `ExecutorService` instances and want your flow stages to be processed on different but particular threads, then no. You have two choices from here:

1) If the only requirement is being on different threads, but that can change on each independent subscriber, you can use `io()` or `computation()`

2) If you want to thread-confine the stages for each independent subscriber, you can either use multiple `Schedulers.from(Executor)` with your `ExecutorService` or use `RxJavaPlugins.createNewSingleScheduler(ThreadFactory)`. If you take the chance to rely on internal components, you can also just `new SingleScheduler()`.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to process the objects I push to my `Subject` on a single thread. My `ExecutorService` is local and I don't care which tread pushes to my `Subject`. __Note that__ I only have one `Subscriber`.

Comment: Then you can use any of `Schedulers.single()` or `Schedulers.from(Executor)`.